# Making JButton in one class open seperate JDialog class

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am creating a quiz and have created a class with a JFrame which sort of acts like the main menu. On this menu, I have created a JButton which I want to open the seperate JDialog (which will contain the questions etc).

The JDialog is a seperate class called questionDialog.java

I believe you have to implement an action listener calling setVisible(true) however when I do that, I get a cannot make static reference to non-static method setvisible error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am using eclipse and Jigloo for the GUI

here is my code in my main menu JFrame class, specifically the code for the button I want to open the new JDialog
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                NewJFrame inst = new NewJFrame();
                inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                inst.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

```
 startButton = new JButton();
        getContentPane().add(startButton);
        startButton.setText("Start Quiz");
        startButton.setBounds(454, 239, 65, 23);
```

And here is the code which gives me the error

```
startButton = new JButton();
        getContentPane().add(startButton);
        startButton.setText("Start Quiz");
        startButton.setBounds(454, 239, 65, 23);
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionevent)
            {
                questionDialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
```

Here is the code from the seperate JDialog class

```
package ZillionaireGUI;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class questionDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                questionDialog inst = new questionDialog(frame);
                inst.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public questionDialog(JFrame frame) {
        super(frame);
        initGUI();
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        try {
            setSize(400, 300);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: The code you posted has no errors. Where exactly are you seeing the error?

Comment: @peeskillet I don't see an error either. I think @user3455584 is trying to open the questionDialog by calling `questionDialog.setVisible(true)`. Is that the case?

Comment: @SharpKnight yes that is correct, however when I try doing this I get the aforementioned error

Comment: POst your code with the actionListener()

Comment: I have edited my post with the action listener

Comment: See my answer. Should work out for you

Comment: I would like to add the reason for the error you receive: you are trying to call `setVisible()` on the _class_ `questionDialog` (in a static way), while you actually want to call it on an _instance_ of `questionDialog`, because `setVisible()` is not a static method (after all, you want to make _one_ dialog visible).

Comment: I have read your answer and it makes a lot of sense. I would just like to comment, would it be easier to call an _instance_ of my questionDialog class, or would it be simpler to do the method @peeskillet mentioned below?

Comment: _"would it be easier to call an instance of my questionDialog class, or would it be simpler to do the method @peeskillet mentioned below?"_ - What do you think `new questionDialog()` is? It's an _instance_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you should do.

1. Get rid of the `main` method in the `JDialog` class. Your application should only have *one* `main` method, and that should be in your `JFrame` class.
2. Don't create a new `JFrame` to pass it to your dialog.
3. To open it on a button click just create a `new questionDialog()` passing the current frame to it. Something like this

   ```
   public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
      public MyFrame() {
          JButton but = new JButton("but");
          but.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  QuestionDialog dialog = new QuestionDialog(MyFrame.this);
                  dialog.setVisible(true);
              }
          });
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
              public void run() {
                  new MyFrame();
              } 
          });
      }
   }

   public class QuestionDialog extends JDialog {
       public QuestionDialog(Frame parent) {
           super(parent);
       }
   }
   ```

---

**Bonus**

- You are getting the error doing `questionDialog.setVisible(true)` because `setVisible` is an instance method and you are trying to call it in a static way. You need to create a `new` instance of your dialog class to call it.
- Use Java naming convention. Class names begin with capital letters.
  `questionDialog` → `QuestionDialog`

Comment: when you say do not create a new JFrame, are you referring to the JDialog I have created, or something else? You threw me off a little when you said that!

Comment: NO I mean `JFrame frame = new JFrame()`. You don't need that. It's useless. You want to reference the main class JFrame and not a `new JFrame`. My code shows how to do that

Comment: Ah I see. Its making much more sense to me now, my mind seems to have gone blank. My final question would be to implement a similar version of your code in my main class or in my questionDialog class?

Comment: I don't see any reason for it to be in your main frame class. Application opens main frame -> button gets pressed in main frame -> dialog opens. If that's the functionality you want, then the code above is how you want it.

Comment: Hmm. I implemented the code as you said in the my dialog class, do I not need to then implement some form of code in my main class now?

Comment: Sorry my last comment was backwards. I meant to say I dont see any reason for it to be in your dialog class. See my updated code

Comment: Brilliant! It now works, could I just ask, what does the 'SwingUtilties invoke later' part of the code do? The button seems to be working without me implementing this

Comment: It's to run your application in the Event Dispatch Thread, as all Swing apps should be done. See more at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Also don't forget to accept this answer, it helped you out (the check mark).

Comment: I see. I've just looked and in my main class I have something similar , I've displayed this in my original post

Comment: Yup that's how it goes.

Comment: Ah, I'm using Jigloo to help create my GUI so sometimes I miss out on these little things. Thanks for all of your help, I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your main menu write the following

```
 startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
 {  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               JFrame frame = new JFrame();
               questionDialog inst = new questionDialog(frame);
               inst.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is likely that you are trying to do something to a non-static member while you are in main (which is a static method). You should just use main to create an instance and then call some method of that instance. I've put some working code below:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Zillionaire extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton startButton;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Zillionaire zillionaire = new Zillionaire();
        zillionaire.init();
    }

    private void init() {
        startButton = new JButton();
        // Removed: we just use add now, and bets to do this last.
//        getContentPane().add(startButton); 
        startButton.setText("Start Quiz");
        startButton.setBounds(454, 239, 65, 23);
        startButton.addActionListener(this);
        // Add after the button is configured, not before
        add(startButton);

        // This just makes our JFrame pretty and visible
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    // Anything that implements the ActionListener interface can listen
    // for the button being pressed and activate the JDialog
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.out.println("Button pressed, but Dialog doesn't do much");
        QuestionDialog questionDialog = new QuestionDialog(this);
    }

}

class QuestionDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    public QuestionDialog(JFrame frame) {
        super(frame);
        initGUI();
    }

    // Set it visible when we make our GUI
    private void initGUI() {
        try {
            setSize(400, 300);
            // Added so we can see something
            add(new JLabel("I should add something!"));
            setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```